# Getting error after wsp deployment - The Web application at xxxx could not be found

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, alternate-access-mapping

> The Web application at xxxx could not be found. Verify that you have typed the URL correctly. If the URL should be serving existing content, the system administrator may need to add a new request URL mapping to the intended application.

I am getting above error whenever I deploy a `wsp` solution and try to access it using  internet URL before internal URL.

This is strange but if I access it using internal URL first then the page would open fine on internet URL also.

However, after a day or two it starts throwing same error again. And the error won't go away until the page is opened from the server using Internal URL.

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I solved it myself-
In Alternate Access Mapping's Internet URL, I was using the IP address.

Changing that IP address to domain did the trick.